# FlywayException: Unable to scan for SQL migrations in location: classpath:db/migration

Tags: java, database, maven, flyway

I'm trying to start using flyway with maven integration but can't make it work.

I'm following the documentation seems to be very simple so no strange things seem to be done.

My **pom.xml** is the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Flyway plugin configuration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</url>
                    <user>test_fede</user>
                    <password>test_fede</password>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.21</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DB dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have the directory **resources/db/migration/** without any migration yet.

When I issuing flyway:info on cygwin or cmd I got an flyway error:

```
$ mvn compile flyway:info
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.test:test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [compile, flyway:info]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [flyway:info {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test (MySQL 5.5)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to scan for SQL migrations in location: classpath:db/migration

Embedded error: Unable to determine URL for classpath location: db/migration (ClassLoader: org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader@5bcdbf6)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Tue May 06 11:06:15 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/223M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can give me a hand on this?

Thans a lot.

Comment: Check my this answer hopefully it becomes helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59478383/9437031

Comment: Check this is may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65561481/6150881

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, just for you to know.

I found the problem, it happens when we setup flyway in our environment but we don't have any migration to be executed.

It shouldn't display a classpath error but fortunately it's working.

By the way, another problem I found is that after executing **init** if we check with **info** nothing is displayed. And if we add a new migration with **V1** then **info** won't show it unless we change it to **V1_1**

Hope to help

Comment: This was probably due to maven not creating the output directory if the input directory is empty. P.S.: You probably don't need init. That's for existing databases only. For new ones migrate is enough.

Answer (score 18):

This also happens if the compile goal is not executed before calling flyway:migrate. Actually this IS included in the quick start manual. It says:

> mvn **compile** flyway:migrate

However if you miss that detail and start to just call `mvn flyway:migrate`, the SQL file will not get copied into the target directory (actually the target directory will not even exist) and you get this cryptic error.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem and it was because when I created the migration directory I gave it the name `db.migration` directly.

By creating the directory `db` and then inside it the `migration` directory it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem. In my case, I had my migration script in the wrong directory that had caused the issue. I moved the script V1__Create_person_table.sql to the right directory at resources/db/migration/ and it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. But when i obeserved the logs keenly i found flywaydb is looking in db/migration folder for the script but my script is in db/migrate. so, after correcting the path from db/migrate to db/migration it works!!.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem too. in my case i thought i had named the directories correctly after triple checking everything. Turned out that i typed `migrations` instead of `migration`. As soon as i fixed this everything was fine.

Just before this i had another issue with the underscore after the version marker (V1) in the migration filename. It needs to be a dunder (double underscore) so its always `V1__description.sql` .

Seems like none of the flyway issues i encounter are big mess-up's. it's always something small that can be easily fixed. It's just about finding out what the problem is. That's the hard part.

Comment: Wow 3 hours later, thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dumb mistake I've made where I got this pesky error:

Make sure you set your packaging as `jar` not `pom` in your *pom.xml*. Then `mvn install` and make sure you have a jar for that project in your M2 folder otherwise you will get this error since the migration file wasn't copied over and found.