# Flyway: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration]

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I created an new project with springboot2.2.0.M2 / Flyway 5.2.4 / Java8.
After try to start my project i got :

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

2019-04-22 13:36:54.574  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo214.Demo214Application   : Starting Demo214Application on xx-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 17268
2019-04-22 13:36:54.577  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo214.Demo214Application   : The following profiles are active: dev
2019-04-22 13:36:54.665  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-04-22 13:36:54.665  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-04-22 13:36:55.731  WARN 17268 --- [  restartedMain] o.m.s.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner      : No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.example.demo214]' package. Please check your configuration.
2019-04-22 13:36:55.939  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2019-04-22 13:36:55.943  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-04-22 13:36:55.983  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 9ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-04-22 13:36:56.412  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$631e07b5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-04-22 13:36:56.875  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-04-22 13:36:56.901  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-04-22 13:36:56.902  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
2019-04-22 13:36:57.103  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-04-22 13:36:57.103  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2438 ms
2019-04-22 13:36:57.257  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.d.s.b.a.DruidDataSourceAutoConfigure : Init DruidDataSource
2019-04-22 13:36:57.413  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource   : {dataSource-1} inited
2019-04-22 13:36:58.008  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
 _ _   |_  _ _|_. ___ _ |    _ 
| | |\/|_)(_| | |_\  |_)||_|_\ 
     /               |         
                        3.1.0 
Mon Apr 22 13:36:58 CST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2019-04-22 13:36:59.143  WARN 17268 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
2019-04-22 13:36:59.144  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-04-22 13:36:59.170  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource   : {dataSource-1} closed
2019-04-22 13:36:59.172  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-04-22 13:36:59.184  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-04-22 13:36:59.197 ERROR 17268 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo214.Demo214Application.main(Demo214Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.checkLocationExists(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:194) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.flyway(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:153) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e31bd555.CGLIB$flyway$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e31bd555$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$169da02e.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e31bd555.flyway(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have a init sql under db/migration with name: `V1.0.0__init.sql` (just one line in it: `use mydb;`)

my flyway configuration in yml (ignore other datasource):

```
spring:
  flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    locations: classpath:db/migration
```

I tried to debug it, found the `FlywayAutoConfiguratioin.hasAtLeastOneLocation()` always return false, it means not found the location (but the `location` looks like right in debugger), see the following screenshot:

[image]

appreciate any kind help :)

Comment: Not sure but try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59478383/9437031

Comment: Check my this answer hopefully it becomes helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59478383/9437031

Comment: This helped me out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65561481/6150881

Answer (score 57):

Make sure that you have not accidentally created a folder with the name db.migration, as opposed to the folders db/migration.
Intellij will show both as db.migration in the project files view, when you have the option "Compact Middle Packages" enabled.

Comment: +1 Exactly my issue caused by typing `db.migration` as a new folder. I highly recommend to create `db` first and *then* `migration` folder in it.

Comment: thanks a lot.. i spent 5 hours on fixing this and this was the solution.. Unbelievable.. how much life i wasted and thanks for this.

Comment: in intellij change the view of project to project files and check the structure really as it says db.migration is db/migration

Answer (score 14):

Try to use in Spring Boot `application.properties`:

```
spring.flyway.check-location = false
```

It switches off Flyway migration scripts presents check.

Also see a set of default Flyway variables for Spring Boot

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 10):

Mostly it happen because of copy paste. Make sure that you copy the script after creating folder structure like below

```
resources/
        db/
          migration/
            _init.sql
```

IntelliJ shows both db.migration and db/migration to same as db.migration. 
You can actual structure by clicking on top right gear sign and tick of flatten package. Hope this helps.

Comment: Had this issue. Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V may create a folder named `db.migration` instead of creating the structur `db/migration` in IntelliJ 2019.3.

Comment: /src/main/resources/db/migration/

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem and for me helped creating new empty file in migration folder :

for example - init.sql

Comment: this is awkward, but it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

For me the name of the scheme `V1_1_schema.sql` was wrong.
Changing it to `V1_1__schema.sql` solved the location issue.

Seems like Flyway requires double underscore `__` in name prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem like this: first we create a "db folder" in "resources", then we create any file in the "db folder", then we create a "migration" subdirectory and already in it we create our migration file

Answer (score 0):

I already created db.migration folders exactly but still got this error, however I added this and it seemed like it worked
`spring.flyway.check-location = false`